# How can I build an inline documentation utility?

Tags: programming, document-creation, code-generation

I often have a large function to which I add inline comments, but then I can't see the forest for the trees. How can I make a tool that extracts the comments and tokens within them to generate an overview or structured outline of the large complex function? For instance:

```
 BigNastyFunction[input_List, xSpecArg_, ySpecArg_, OptionsPattern[]] := 
 Module[
 {
    (*1:1 Local variables*)
   data, ySpecContinousQ, xSpecContinousQ, groupsQ, joinedCounts, colors, ymin, ymax, xmin, 

   (*1:2 Option variables*)
   axesLabelsQ, barOrigin, background, diskSizeScaling, displayFunction, frameQ
 }

  (*2:1 Check for null Input*)
  If[times === {}, Return[$Failed]];

  (*2:2:1 Check for groups *)
  check1 = Depth[input] === 4;  
  (*2:2:2 Check for nongroups *)
  check2 = Depth[input] === 3;  

  etc...
```

Would be transformed into something like:

Outline of BigNastyFunction

Part 1.

.....Step 1. Local variables

.....Step 2. Option variables

Part 2.

.....Step 1. Check for null Input

.....Step 2.

..........a) Check for groups

..........b) Check for nongroups

Comment: Do you program in the notebook FrontEnd or in Wolfram Workbench or in vi ?

Comment: @RolfMertig You forgot Emacs :)

Comment: @belisarius no, I did think about it. but then I did not want to bore people too much and stick with the most common editors.

Comment: @RolfMertig I can program in either.

Comment: At risk of stating the obvious, you could always just change the comment highlighting color to something more visible, perhaps temporarily, e.g. `SetOptions[$FrontEndSession, 
 AutoStyleOptions -> {"CommentStyle" -> {FontColor -> 
      RGBColor[1., 0.5, 0.], ShowAutoStyles -> False, 
     ShowSyntaxStyles -> False, AutoNumberFormatting -> False}}
 ]`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would suggest something more simple-minded than Rolf's sophisticated implementation:

```
Clear[extractComments];
extractComments[boxes_] :=
  StringJoin@
    Riffle[
      Cases[boxes, 
          r : RowBox[{"(*", ___, "*)"}] :> 
              StringJoin@Cases[r, _String, Infinity], Infinity],
      "\n"];
```

and the palette:

```
CreatePalette[
  Button["Comments",
    With[{read = NotebookRead[SelectedNotebook[]]},
      SelectionMove[SelectedNotebook[], After, Cell];
      NotebookWrite[SelectedNotebook[], Cell[extractComments[read]]]
    ]
  ]]
```

You select your function's cell and press the "Comments" button. This seems to work in simple cases I tested. You can modify the `extractComments` function to implement more complex logic that would categorize the comments according to their hierarchy etc.

Comment: Nice, though this will get you all comments, not just those with ":" in it.

Comment: Maybe there should be some kind of MDoc, like JavaDoc ... And then these things would be easy ...

Comment: @RolfMertig re - *not just those with ":"* - indeed, but it is very easy to postprocess, to filter out those without it.  Re: MDoc - indeed, but I thought something like this existed already? Of course, this can work only of this becomes a widely used standard.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin Nice comment grabber. But I think the project of an general inline documentation utility remains a worthy goal.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin how might I adapt this to WorkBench and extracting comments for a symbol from a file?

Comment: @Mike I don't see a simple way, since Eclipse is a different environment.

Answer (score 10):

OK, FrontEnd:
After creating the "overview" button below just click first on your function definition and then on the button and under the function definition you will get (nearly) what you want, i.e. :

Part 1.

Step 1. Local variables

Part 1.

Step 2. Option variables

Part 2.

Step 1. Check for null Input

Part 2.

Step 2.:1 Check for groups

Part 2.

Step 2.:2 Check for nongroups

```
  CreatePalette@Cell[BoxData[
 ButtonBox["overview",
  ButtonFunction:>Block[{$CellContext`com}, SelectionMove[
          SelectedNotebook[], All, CellContents]; $CellContext`com = 
     ExportString[
       StringDrop[
        Apply[StringJoin, 
         StringCases[
          Apply[StringJoin, $CellContext`RER = ReplaceRepeated[
                 NotebookRead[
                  InputNotebook[]], RowBox[
                   Condition[
                    Pattern[$CellContext`x, 
                 BlankSequence[]], 
                Not[
                 FreeQ[$CellContext`x, RowBox]]]] :> Apply[RowBox, 
                   ReplaceAll[{$CellContext`x}, RowBox[{
                       Pattern[$CellContext`y, 
                        BlankSequence[]]}] :> $CellContext`y]]]], {
          StringExpression["(*", 
             Shortest[
              Pattern[$CellContext`i, 
                   Blank[]]], ":", 
                 Shortest[
                  Pattern[$CellContext`j, 
               BlankSequence[]]], 
             Shortest[
              Pattern[$CellContext`str, 
                   BlankSequence[]]], "*)"] :> {
                 StringExpression["\nPart ", $CellContext`i, 
                  StringJoin[".\n", "Step "], $CellContext`j, 
                  "."], $CellContext`str}}]], 1], "Text"]; SelectionMove[
          SelectedNotebook[], After, Cell]; NotebookWrite[
          SelectedNotebook[], 
          Cell[$CellContext`com, "Text"]]],
  Evaluator->Automatic]]]
```